# creating, passing, getting back Array of a Struct and loop throuh it in C

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I need to execute a function that returns array of a specified `struct` with variable length. Then I should loop through the returned array.

example struct :

```
typedef struct student {
  int id;
  char *name;
  int grade;
} Student;
```

function prototypes 1 :

```
Student *students; 
students = findStudentByGrade(int grade);
```

function prototypes 2 :

```
Student *students;
int retval = findStudentByGrade(&students, int grade);
```

I am bit confused on above methods. How can correctly define a array of struct? call function ? and loop through it untill end? Can some one help me please.

Comment: `specified struct with variable length` what do you mean by that ? Your structure size would be 2+2 [char pointer]+2 = 6 , you are just storing the pointer to char in struct.

Comment: @Praksh, `specified struct` mean the struct which I have shown in code. `Student`

Comment: @BhaveshMunot i wanted to clear the doubt before code :)

Comment: @BlueBird I understood it's `struct Student`, but how it is of variable length ?

Comment: @BlueBird Understood, you can use linked lists for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this in this way. This code is working. I tested in CodeLite.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct student {
    int id;
    char *name;
} Student;

Student *findStudent(int *asize, const int grade);

int main(void)
{
    Student *stds;
    int asize = 0;
    stds = findStudent(&asize, 5);
    int i;  
    for (i = 0; i < asize; i++) {
        printf("ID : %i\n", stds[i].id);
    }
    return 0;
}

Student *findStudent(int *asize, const int grade)
{
    struct student *stds = malloc(sizeof(struct student) * 3);
    stds[0].id = 10;
    stds[1].id = 20;
    stds[2].id = 40;
    *asize = 3;
    return stds;
}
```

Get the array of struc as returned statement and pass an int variable with argument list to get the size back and simply loop through using a for loop. Or else you will find problem in looping. It is more easy to get the array size from the function which create the array.

Comment: mhh this makes sense,, what is the option if i want to calculate the array length uisng array itself without passing an extra argument?

Comment: @BlueBird you cannot since you are returning a pointer, the only way is either to return a value like fSazy did or allocate one extra, empty record as an end record then loop until you find that.

Answer (score 1):

I mean this is quite a basic question, but:

Defining array of your structures would look like:

```
 int size = ...;
 Student *students = (Student*) malloc(sizeof(Student) * size);
```

Then just pass that to the function (both size and the array) and then just loop until i < size.

Ofcourse, don't forget to:

```
 free(students);
```

at the end.